# How to calculate simple stochastic integral?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Can you suggest how can I calculate $\int_0^t e^{cs}dW_s$ where $W_s $ is Brownian motion and $c$ is constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $X_t=\int_0^te^{cs}\,dW_s$, deduce that $dX_t=e^{ct}dW_t$ and use Ito's Lemma.

Comment: Well, I've obtained that $X_t$ from Ito's Lemma and I don't know if I should return to $dX_t$